# Html.fromHtml not working as desired

Tags: android

As said, `Html.fromHtml()` is not working. Here is the string which needs to be displayed in html format -

```
&lt;p&gt;vehethtehetggebebetbefbthtehethehetheth,ethethtehethethet&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;ethetheyjyerjwehweryjetkteukejryjryje&lt;\/p&gt;
```

This is the code which I am using for displaying text

```
holder.lblDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(object.get(position).getProduct().getProductDescription()));
```

This is what I get in display -
[image: This is what I get in display]

Thanks in advance :)

**Found the solution**

I have downloaded library from [apache (commons lang)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)
And used this piece of code for displaying it -

```
String description = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(object.get(position).getProduct().getProductDescription());
holder.lblDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(description));
```

And this is the result -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        String s = "&lt;p&gt;vehethtehetggebebetbefbthtehethehetheth,ethethtehethethet&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;ethetheyjyerjwehweryjetkteukejryjryje&lt;\\/p&gt;";

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;",">")));
```

**UPDATE:**

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(s).toString()));
```

You will get the result

[image]

Comment: This will work. But if other such escape sequence are provided code won't work. I have figured out the way out for this, posting it in main question

Comment: Check my updated answer. No need third-party library

Comment: Cool. This works fine. I tried this earlier without casting therefore I came up with the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
holder.lblDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>"+object.get(position).getProduct().getProductDescription()+"</p>"));
```

Comment: What displayed using the above solution?

Comment: Remove the tags (e.g. &lt;p&gt;) mixed up in the string and just pass plain string using the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple and will surely work.

```
    String s1 = Html.fromHtml(object.get(position).getProduct().getProductDescription()).toString();

       holder.lblDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(s1));
```

Comment: It's already a string. And also I tried for checking it out. It's not working. Same response as above