# Html.fromHtml() on TextView not working with layouts added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the `Html.fromHtml()` function to set the text of a TextView in multiple screens. All of them are of the following pattern: `<a href="http://link.com">Name</a>`. I used the Log to see if the strings were correct, and they are.

But there's one common thing on the two cases that aren't working: i'm inflating and copying a row layout.

I'm using a LinearLayout as a row and adding multiple of these inside another linearlayout.

The row layout that is being copied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bandName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Band"
        android:textColor="@color/darkTxtLightBg"
        android:textColorLink="@color/darkTxtLightBg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bandOnTour"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Band"
        android:textColor="@color/darkTxtLightBg"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout where i insert the rows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_bandList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

The code where i copy, populate and add these views:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout tr;
for (Band b : bandsFollowed) {
     tr = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bandrow_followedlist, null);
     TextView t1 = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.bandName);
     t1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + b.url + "\">" + b.name + "</a>"));
     t1 = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.bandOnTour);
     t1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.onTour));
     t1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bandFollowed));
     tl.addView(tr);
}
```

What i tried:

- Set all the parent layouts to `android:clickable="true"`, but it made no difference.
- Using the `android:onClick` attribute with a function, but that won't work as i need to.
- Using a TableLayout and TableRows instead of LinearLayouts, but i had the same problem.

So, why does it work when i simply set a text to another TextView that i have, but it doesn't work when i add them dynamically? Could it be something with the inflater, the parent or even the xml file?

I know the link is there because the text is underlined, but nothing happens when i click it.

Comment: Please read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242692/html-fromhtml-not-working-as-desired/32243258#32243258) to see if it works for you or not

Comment: @BNK Didn't work, but thanks for the help. It's like the link was there, the Text is underlined with some link, but when i click nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, I have tested. Hope this helps!

```
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        final String htmlString="<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Go to Google</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I used that line before on another activity, but i forgot to add the `setMovementMethod` on the other one... My mistake.